# Calling Webservice asynchoronously using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have build a webservice using asp.net in C# and that's running on say
"http://ABC.com/WebSite1/Service.asmx" and I'm trying to consume this service from another asp.net website page using jquery ajax call asynchronously. But the service url is not getting hit and I'm getting an Error message.

```
This is my webservice:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment   
the following line. 
[ScriptService]
public class Service : WebService
{
    public Service () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void GetUserDetails(string Email, string StreetAddress, string City, string     State, string ZipCode, string Phone) {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM OrderTb WHERE Email = '" + Email + "' AND StreetAddress = '" + StreetAddress + "' AND City = '" + City + "' AND State = '" + State +"' AND ZipCode = '" + ZipCode +"' AND Phone = '"+ Phone + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    // Create an instance of DataSet.
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
        }

}
```

And this is my aspx page including the javascript:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"   Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Getting Data from WebService</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
    function GetShippingData() {
        var email = $("#txtEmail").val();
        var street = $("#txtStreetAddress").val();
        var city = $("#txtCity").val();
        var state = $("#txtState").val();
        var zipCode = $("#txtZipCode").val();
        var phone = $("#txtPhone").val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://abc.com/WebSite1/Service.asmx/GetUserDetails',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            data: { Email: email, StreetAddress: street, City: city, State: state,   ZipCode: zipCode, Phone: phone },
            success: function (result) {
                alert('success!');
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Enter Email:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail"  runat="server">abc@gmail.com</asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Enter StreetAddress:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStreetAddress" runat="server">70 abc  road</asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Enter City:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server">Kolkata</asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Enter State:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server">ABC</asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Enter ZipCode:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtZipCode" runat="server">123232</asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Enter Phone:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server">1234567890</asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="GetShippingData();" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvUserDetails" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Record Found">
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the following in your web.config (in your webservice)

```
 <system.web>
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
```

Also can you provide the error your getting incase this isn't the solution

**EDIT:**

Try writing the data value in your ajax call like the following:

```
data: "{ Email: '" + email + "', StreetAddress: '" + street + "', City: '" + city + "', State: '" + state + "',   ZipCode: '" + zipCode + "', Phone: '" + phone "'}"
```

Comment: I have tried the suggested in web.config. But it didn't work. My main problem is the service URL is not getting hit by the asynchronous ajax call and i am getting the error message which i have set in the error attribute in the ajax function.I am doing this in ASP.net Developement Server in visual studio 2010.

Comment: Well it still doesn't say what the error is. I provided another solution that fixed one of my problems. Maybe it will fix yours. But maybe try to inspect the result object that gets return by the error callback and see if you can't find the error reason